# How to get user details from different domain 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, directorysearcher

I am trying to get the user details from different domain but its throwing the following error:

`An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll but was not handled in user code`

**Code as as below:**

```
// Getting domain
var context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "alpha");
Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(context);

using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher())
{
    var de = new DirectoryEntry(domain.Name);
    searcher.SearchRoot = de;
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", "myusername");

    // *** ERROR HERE ***        
    var results = searcher.FindAll();
}
```

I have already tried running visual studio as Domain Admin but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything in inner exception?

Comment: Are you trying to read from a different domain than the one you are connected to? Have you tried specifying the complete LDAP string to the DC (LDAP://xxx) in the DirectoryEntry constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code only works when you add name space using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory and also add a reference.

```cs
// Get user name
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
var domainName = username.Split('\\')[0];

// Getting domain
var directoryContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domainName);
Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(directoryContext);

using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            // Get details here
            var name = user.GivenName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me until I get to the PrincipalContext then it throws the same exception as the question.  I am reading from a different domain so I'm sure that is part of the problem.